# Bad reopen-review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

How could this become a candidate for a reopen-review-audit?

[Why is select before where necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773183/why-is-select-before-where-necessary)

I think, it is easy to reason for a reopen-vote here:

The question can be answered in a way, which is potentially useful to others, (as it has been done by one answerer).

Please remove this question from audits. Thank you.

Comment: It's essentially asking the reasoning behind a language design decision ("logic behind it"). So the only person who can authoritatively answer that is someone on the spec committee. Everyone else will have to guesstimate and give their _opinion_ on why that was there.

Comment: What makes you think this is a good question? I mean, if you're going to dispute a review audit, you need to actually… *dispute* it.

Comment: @CodyGray A good indication is for example that it has a good answer in my eyes. It clarifies to the asker, that there might be other operations than a query, that needs a where-clause

Comment: A good answer does not make a question on-topic. That is not a good reason. You're supposed to evaluate the question itself. Why does this question need to be re-opened?

Comment: @CodyGray Because I disagreed with the reason why it was closed. While I accept, that you had given a different verdict, I do not see, that I am more wrong than you.

Comment: I agree with @CodyGray here. You are not giving any legitimate reasons in your meta-post on why this question should be reopened. To be able to have a discussion about this you should give some insight on what makes this is a good question in your opinion. You are not *"more wrong"*, you simply don't give any reason at all so there is nothing to dispute here...

Comment: @Wilt Well, what else can I say than "I find the question reasonable", since there is the possibility to give a useful answer to it (which has also been done, btw). I do not think it is "primarily opinion based". In fact, it is "primarily opinion based" if you consider it to be closed or not, so it is not suitable for an audit. Suitable are only absolutely clear cases, and I dispute that this is the case here.

Comment: I haven't given any verdict at all! I wasn't one of the people who voted to close that question, nor did I review it in any queue. I don't actually think I'm very qualified to render a decision on the subject, since I know nothing about the technologies relevant to the question. All I know is that 5 people thought it was a question that should be closed, and one person says it shouldn't have been. Those 5 people gave a reason, the one person just said "disagree"/"dispute". That doesn't tell me anything useful. If you want to open a Meta dispute, then you need to give reasons.

Comment: This issue of not thinking that the question is opinion-based is not an argument that you presented in your question. It only came up after I asked why you disagreed with the audit, which was kind of the point of asking why. Of course, it would be helpful to go on to explain *why* you don't think it is opinion-based. And do consider editing this objection into your question itself, so everyone else won't have to read all of the comments to understand the issue.

Comment: @CodyGray I am tired of this, I just tried to bring up a bad choice for an audit and asked to remove it. I thought, it is self-explaining why this is the case. As you can see in the answer below, bad audits are system-inherent and unavoidable. If you disagree, vote down the question and move on, this harassment here is inappropriate.

Comment: I am quite offended that you claim I am *harassing* you. I asked you to provide an explanation for why you think this is an invalid review audit so that I could have more information to make an informed decision. You replied to me, and I replied back. Sorry you don't like having to justify your opinions. Nothing is self-explaning. There is a whole network of Q&A sites devoted to explaining things to people about various disciplines. Tim doesn't say this is a bad audit. He explains how audits are chosen, and why this one looked fine to the system. He actually recommends you do what I tried.

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry if you are offended, but this is how it feels. I multiply told you why I think, the question is valid, you just ignore that and keep pushing. Again: The question can be answered in a way, which is potentially useful to others, as it has been done by one answerer.

Comment: The *"told you why I think"* should be in the post. That is all...

Comment: @Wilt Ok, did that...

Comment: @Ctx I don't agree with your basic argument here - the fact that you can give a good answer doesn't prove that it's a good question.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Well, but this wasn't asked for anyway, the question was, if it should have been closed. Downvoting is appropriate for questions "not good"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that we can programmatically determine about that question that indicates it might be contentious if presented as an audit. Just stuff we can tell about it:

- It has been closed and negatively scored since January 21
- It never received a reopen vote
- It has only one answer, with a single upvote
- It received more views in the last few hours than the entire time it existed

... every data point *about* the question tells us that it's almost certainly useful as a review task. Remember, review tasks are *solely* for slowing folks down that aren't paying a great deal of attention to what they're doing. Imagine them to be something similar to a speed bump (with roughly the same amount of intelligence).

It's perfectly okay to realize you're at odds with the decision that the community made. In fact, it's more or less expected that will happen from time to time.

Cases where folks are simply robo-reviewing, or perhaps more importantly more likely to be at odds than in agreement with the majority of audits they see are two points where the best thing the system can do is ask you to wait a while - and give you an opportunity to talk to us about it.

If you hit an audit and strongly disagree with it, burying the question as an audit is probably the *worst* thing we could do for you. The best thing to do is kick off a discussion to explain why you think the question is valid, get feedback, make edits that might help and then *possibly get it re-opened* :)

Comment: Yes, I fully understand and agree with you. Indeed, I neither question the review audit system as a whole, nor do I have a good proposal to change it in general. I just asked to remove it from audits since I think, this is a bordercase. This is done all the time, I wonder, why it should be a problem here ;) And I do not insist to get it re-opened, I accept if more people vote for leaving it closed than the reopen-fraction. I just don't think I have made a bad job reviewing this question and tried to prevent others from failing this audit, too.